# Chinese Character Reading: What browser-based chat sites are available from inside China?

Tags: characters, technology

While reading Chinese on the web I use a the [Chinese Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-console/mekipefdgdacoicbibojhhjppiiaoidp?hl=en) Chrome Extension which helps me hover over characters and know what they are.

I've recently started connecting with language practice partners in iTalki to practice Mandarin. They all want to use skype, but when they type in the chat I have no tool on the desktop-app to help me with the characters.

I would normally use Google Hangouts, or Facebook, for this, to help me with the reading.

Is there any browser based chat (video not required) that my practice partners inside of China can use?

Thank you!

Update:

I found that Skype actually has a web version, so that works fine, though I should try to make qq/wechat work also...

Comment: https://wx.qq.com/, https://web.telegram.org/

Answer (score 2):

The usual place for Chinese people to chat is WeChat.  You can login and chat using a browser via the link https://wx.qq.com/.

Here's a screenshot of me chatting with my Chinese teacher:

[image]

I'm using the [Zhongwen Chinese Popup Dictionary extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zhongwen-chinese-english/).

Comment: It tells me "new wechat users" can't access the web version

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize.  I login via my phone.